How to install and run daltonproject with dalton project?
I have downloaded and installed daltonproject as well as dalton program but when I try to run a script through Python I got this error:
Python 3.9.2 (default, Feb 28 2021, 17:03:44)
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import daltonproject as dp
>>> dft = dp.QCMethod('DFT', 'B3LYP')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'daltonproject' has no attribute 'QCMethod'

I dont know where is the problem since I'm sure that I cloned well the GitHub repository of Daltonproject.

From the docs, it looks like it should be daltonproject.qcmethod.QCMethod.
